Is it possible to change which display the boot screens display on on an All-in-One?
Recently, I smashed the screen of my Dell Optiplex 9030 All-in-One. To replace it, I bought another one with the same specs (It was cheaper than replacing the screen) and moved the hard drive over. Now, I am trying to install Linux on an empty hard drive and use the smashed computer as a home server. However, I can't seem to get it to boot into the boot usb. I'm not sure what's stopping it from booting, and was wondering if it was possible to make the computer output the boot and bios screens to an external display.

I'd look for a serial console or UART connection on the motherboard. It would be a 3- or 4-pin header or just through holes (as on this board on the bottom edge, right side). If you're lucky it will emit boot info to help solve the problem.

Would it be the connector labelled BIOS_DEBUG on the motherboard?

Could be. Use a voltmeter or oscilloscope to find the GND pin on that header. Then find the pin or pins that are 5V or 3.3V. Those are the possible pins that would have the TxD output. Connect the ground and RxD of a USB-to-serial-TTL adapter for the appropriate voltage (5 or 3.3 volts) to receive any messages.
